# Converting HTML Canvas to Image. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to export my HTML Canvas to an Image. But when I export the image, I keep getting the img src = "undefined".  I printed the canvas to the page directly and confirmed I am getting the correct canvas.  Here's the code that I'm using.  Please let me know what you see is wrong. May be a problem with CORS (This is HTML5)?

```
scope.getShuttleImage = function () {
            var tmpPng
            var imageElement
            html2canvas(document.body.getElementsByClassName("shuttle-truck"), {
                useCORS: true, 
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    tmpPng = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                }
            });
            document.write('<img src= "' + tmpPng+'"/>"') // Just for testings sake
        };
```

Comment: Move the `document.write()` into the `onrendered` handler.  That event handler is running *after* you add the image to the page.

Comment: Thank you. That was a pretty dorky mistake

Comment: Heh - it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is with `html2canvas` being asynchronous. Try changing your code to the following. Like @Archer said

```
scope.getShuttleImage = function () {
        var tmpPng
        var imageElement
        html2canvas(document.body.getElementsByClassName("shuttle-truck"), {
            useCORS: true, 
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                tmpPng = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                document.write('<img src= "' + tmpPng+'"/>"') // Just for testings sake

            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thanks! Early morning goof